# Select sum of items based on their monthly entry date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select sum of items based on their monthly entry date:

The Inventory table is as below:

```
    EntryDate    Items

    1/1/2013      2
    1/20/2013     5
    1/23/2013     3
    1/30/2013     2
    2/4/2013      4
    2/17/2013     34
```

The desired output with Total row added:

```
    EntryDate    Items

    1/1/2013        2
    1/20/2013       5
    1/23/2013       3
    1/30/2013       2
    **Total         12**
    2/4/2013        4
    2/17/2013       34 
    **Total         38**
```

Below is my attempt. I am trying to do this using rollup but its counting all items at once and not by monthly basis, how to achieve this:

```
Select Convert(date, EntryDate) AS [DATE],SUM(Items) AS Total, 
Case WHEN GROUPING(Items) = 1 THEN 'Rollup'
Else Status end AS Total From [Inventory]  Group by Convert(date, EntryDate) WITH 
Rollup
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you actually want results like your example, you can use the following:

```
SELECT EntryDate, Items
FROM (SELECT YEAR(EntryDate)'Year_',MONTH(EntryDate)'Month_',CAST(EntryDate AS VARCHAR(12))'EntryDate',Items,1 'sort'
      FROM Inventory
      UNION ALL
      SELECT YEAR(EntryDate)'Year_',MONTH(EntryDate)'Month_','Total',SUM(Items)'Items',2 'sort'
      FROM Inventory
      GROUP BY YEAR(EntryDate),MONTH(EntryDate)
      )sub
ORDER BY Year_,Month_,sort
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/abadf/10/0)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will give you the month total in a new column, it will also work when your dates stretch over more than 1 year

```
SELECT EntryDate, Items, 
SUM(Items) OVER (partition by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, entrydate), 0)) Total 
FROM [Inventory]
```

Result:

```
EntryDate   Items   Total
2013-01-01  2       12
2013-01-20  5       12
2013-01-23  3       12
2013-01-30  2       12
2013-02-04  4       38
2013-02-17  34      38
```

Answer (score 0):

**DATEPART** will do try this,

```
SELECT DATEPART(month, EntryDate) AS 'Month Number',sum(items1) FROM ITEMS
GROUP BY DATEPART(month, EntryDate)
```

[# sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/abf84/2)

Comment: Thanks @mari! I need both day wise,Subtotal month wise also like my expected result

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perfect solution for you

```
select isnull(cast(DATEFROMPARTS(year,month,day) as varchar),'Total'), 
       items 
  from (  SELECT datepart(yyyy,EntryDate) year,
                 DATEPART(mm, EntryDate) month, 
                 DATEPART(dd, EntryDate) day,
                 sum(items) items
            From Inventory 
        GROUP BY 
          ROLLUP (datepart(yyyy,EntryDate),
                  DATEPART(mm, EntryDate), 
                  DATEPART(dd, EntryDate) 
                 )
       ) a
 where a.year is not null
   and a.month is not null;
```

[Demo HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ae94/48)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 select entryDate, Items, sum(Items) 
     from (select entryDate,Items, to_date(entry_date, 'mm/yyyy') month_date from Inventory) 
     group by month_date
```